# Dropdownlist formatting using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am basically using a dropdownlist control on an asp.net page, where I have set the width to 150px. In mozilla browser, it is showing the list items expanded, whereas in IE, the list item text is restricted to drop down list's width. Any idea, how can I can get the same appearance of this dropdownlist in IE as it is in Mozilla.

I just want the list items container to be expanded to its maximum width, NOT the dropdownlist box.

Comment: I would think in the direction of setting `max-width` instead of `width` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't set the width of the dropdown and the options independently - that's up to the browser. The only option is to replicate the behaviour of the dropdown list yourself in javascript. Basically you would create something that looks like a dropdown list control and attach a click event handler which would display an absolutely positioned div (or ul) displaying the options. You would then attach an event handler to each option that would hide the options and take the action you need - probably display the option in the text of the dropdown control and store the value (a hidden form field would help here if this is a form you wish to submit). This is a fair bit of work but would have the advantage of looking identical in all browsers as long as you're careful with your css. I don't have time to write the code here but it should be fairly straightforward once you accept that there is no quick fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but the thing I am trying to do is a fix suggested by user, after seeing large text in the dropdownlist. If I try to replce this dropdownlist with some other control,this may require many changes in code behind as well. Isn't it possible to fix this using javascript or CSS?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think the browsers allow you to make the changes you want. You should be able to encapsulate this change by using javascript to generate the new control whenever the old control is present. It can keep (but hide) the old control and update its value once an option has been selected. This way the change should not affect any other code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/avernet/2Gn2c/

```
$("select.ie8-fallback")
    .on('mousedown'   , 'select', expand)
    .on('blur change' , 'select', contract);
```

Although i would recommend using this code only with IE using IE8 if condition.

I would have provided a solution specific to your question if you added any code, But i think you can understand from this.